# Facebook api returns : (#120) Invalid album id when trying to post to a group

Tags: api, facebook, sdk

When I try to post a photo in a group through the API I get an error, the post happens, but without the photo.
I've seen people say it's a bug on Facebook and it happens when there's a question mark (?).
However in my post there is no question mark, does anyone know what it could be?
The error i get is:  **(#120) Invalid album id**
Example:
I am using Facebook SDK for PHP like this, and i have a custom method, like this.

```
public function postPhoto(string $message, string $img_path, string $page, string $id='me')
{
    $photoData = [
        'message' => $message,
        'source' => $this->fb->fileToUpload($img_path),
    ];

    $this->pageAccessToken = $this->getTokenForPage($page);

    try {
        $response = $this->fb->post("/$id/photos", $photoData, $this->pageAccessToken);
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
        $this->post_id =  $graphNode['id'];
    } catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Sprizgola I added an example to the post